# Add condition to regex and convert it from js to vb.net

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

I have this regex expression(match either English or Hebrew chars, but not combined):

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i
```

It works ok, I just need to also add limitaion so no numbers would be allow.

- This should match: `abc`, `אבג`
- This should not be match: `a1`, `1b`, `aא`,

The same limitation also need to be added to this regex expression:

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40 ]+|[\w ]+)$/i
```

Its purpose is the same as the first one, only that spaces are allowed.

- This should match: `abcx`, `abcx ascx`, `דגהק` ,`שגד דשגב`
- This should not be match: `asaceדגעההת`, `ascasv אקיכרעקכ`, `as3`, `a3s`, `אב3ע`

Also, if someone can help me to convert the new regex expression I requested, 
and also this on:

```
/^05\d{8}$/i
```

from JavaScript to VB, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w` if you don't want to allow numbers. If you are using the `/i` flag, you can also just use `[a-z]`.

```js
var regex = /^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40 ]+|[a-zA-Z ]+)$/i;
var texts = ["abcx", "abcx ascx", "דגהק" ,"שגד דשגב", "asaceדגעההת", "ascasv אקיכרעקכ", "as3", "a3s", "אב3ע"];
for(var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
  var text = texts[i];
  console.log(text + ": ", !!text.match(regex));
}
```

Comment: It seems he already has the JavaScript code, but wants to convert the Regex expression to .NET.